# How can I export the results of my dredge function model given the errors I am getting?

Tags: r, model, export-to-csv, mumin

I used lme4 to generate general linear negative binomial models, and dredge to run all combinations of the variables that I had determined were important. However, when I attempted to export the result via write.csv, I got the following error message:

```
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, needconv, value = list(`(Intercept)` = c("1.53538995343218",  : 
  replacement element 1 has 5 rows, need 64
```

When I tried with write_csv, I got a different error message:

```
Error in !is.null(modif) && modif %in% type2colname(column.types, protectedcoltypes) : 
  'length = 12' in coercion to 'logical(1)'
```

I am able to view the data frame in the RStudio viewer, and it appears normal there. From what I looked up, neither error appears to be specifically associated with csv writing functions. How can I export my results?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. What code are you actually running? What rows/columns do you want to be in the CSV file?

Comment: It's just write.csv(x.dredge, "x.dredge.csv"). I want all rows and columns in the dredge output.

Comment: But what type of object is `x.dredge`? Is it a data.frame?

Comment: Yes, it is. I checked with class().

Comment: Well, then include the output of `dput(x.dredge)` in the question so that we can reproduce the issue. How did you create the data.frame from your model? It would be a lot easier to help you if you provided a reproducible example that we can run ourselves and test with.